# My gupshup Bot is not responding to normal text messages, does anyone know why?

Tags: java, gupshup

Cheers, I was testing the example gupshup bot in java following gupshup documentation: https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/gupshup-bot-library-for-java

I had a problem in step 6 of the documentation. The bot responds to me when I send images, files or when the connection is established (when using the 'proxy myBotName' command) but it does not respond to me when I send it a normal message like 'hello' **(this is my problem)**.
This is the class that is generated when loading the project archetype, it is the same as the one seen in the documentation:

```
import io.gupshup.developer.annotations.OnEvent;
import io.gupshup.developer.annotations.OnFile;
import io.gupshup.developer.annotations.OnHttpEndPointRequest;
import io.gupshup.developer.annotations.OnImage;
import io.gupshup.developer.annotations.OnMessage;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.context.BotContext;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.input.EventInput;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.input.FileInput;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.input.HttpEndPointRequestInput;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.input.ImageInput;
import io.gupshup.developer.bot.input.MessageInput;

/**
 * @author Abhishek Nama
 */
public class Bot {
    @OnMessage
    public void msgHandler(MessageInput input, BotContext context) {
    context.logger.log("In message handler - " + input.getMessage());
    context.sendResponse(input.getMessage());
    }

    @OnEvent
    public void eventHandler(EventInput input, BotContext context) {
    context.logger.log("In event handler - " + input.getMessage());
    context.sendResponse(input.getMessage());
    }

    @OnImage
    public void imgHandler(ImageInput input, BotContext context) {
    context.logger.log("In image handler - " + input.getMessage());
    context.sendResponse(input.getMessage());
    }

    @OnFile
    public void fileHandler(FileInput input, BotContext context) {
    context.logger.log("In file handler - " + input.getMessage());
    context.sendResponse(input.getMessage());
    }

    @OnHttpEndPointRequest
    public void httpEndPointRequestHandler(HttpEndPointRequestInput input, BotContext context) {
    context.logger.log("In http end point request handler - " + input.params.toString());
    context.sendResponse(input.params.toString());
    }
}
```

and I leave a capture of the chat with the bot where it is seen that it responds to the connection (detecting an event) and the image but does not respond to normal messages

[capture chat bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQYrt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is its not responding to normal message is because of the `io.gupshup.developer.util.Constants` class:

```
    public static final String TYPE_MSG = "text";
   // public static final String TYPE_MSG = "msg";
```

Previously it was assigned the value `msg`. If we change that to `text` it should work fine.